# Unable to append and remove selected tableview cell JSON id in Array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, append

if i tap on cell i need selected cell eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id not(indexPath.row) in arrSelectedRowsBuy and if i tap it again then the selected id should remove from arrSelectedRowsBuy

**I need selected/remove ids from `eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` to `arrSelectedRowsBuy`**

but in my code i am getting selected row index in arrSelectedRowsBuy like [0,1,2,3] but my `eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` will be [22, 8, 4] . how to get selected row id

**code:** here if i append like this `arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)` then total code not working

```
var arrSelectedRowsBuy:[Int] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventListCell", for: indexPath) as! EventListCell

let indexData = eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row]
cell.titleLbl.text = indexData?.event_title
return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell:EventListCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventListCell
let indexData = eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row]

if arrSelectedRowsBuy.contains(indexPath.row) {
    if let index = arrSelectedRowsBuy.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
        cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "checkbox_inactive")
        
        arrSelectedRowsBuy.remove(at: index)
    }
} else {
    
    cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "blue_tick")
    
    arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(indexPath.row)
}
}
```

Comment: when you are filling your tableView you should do it the way that indexPath be equal to your json Index too. if you don't, for every tap, you need to search through your json, find the id, then delete it which is not very sufficient

Comment: @willow, could you please post an answer.. i got stuck here from long time

Comment: @willow if i change something then getting another issue.. post an answer please

Comment: @willow, i have added `cellForRowAt ` code also

Comment: What is “cell jsonData id”? What is “ row jsonArray id”? It’s not easy to understand what is what in this question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "cell jsonData id and row jsonArray id" means this value (not indexPathrow) =`eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, if i append/remove indexPath.row then it will start from [0,1,2] but my `arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` will be [22, 8, 4] like this

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, how to append/remove `arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` this value from selected row. guide me plz.. got stuck

Comment: I don’t really understand what the issue is in just changing the code so it uses the id instead of the index? When removing you look up the id using indexPath.row and the use remove(where:) instead of remove(at:).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, can you please guide me: my issue is-- actually i need append/remove selected row `entListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` in `arrSelectedRowsBuy` can u modify my post according to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code which can be compiled (but not run) in a Playground which is based on the original code:

```
import UIKit

class EventListCell: UITableViewCell {
    init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var checkImg = UIImageView()
}

struct EventListData {
    var result: Result?

    struct Result {
        var events: [Event]?

        struct Event {
            var id: Int
        }
    }
}

var eventListData: EventListData?
var arrSelectedRowsBuy:[Int] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    let cell:EventListCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventListCell
    let indexData = eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row]

    if arrSelectedRowsBuy.contains(indexPath.row) {
        if let index = arrSelectedRowsBuy.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
            cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "checkbox_inactive")

            arrSelectedRowsBuy.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {

        cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "blue_tick")

        arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Since the question is how to store the data model id in the array instead of the row number, I simply changed the code to do that (and removed an unnecessary call to `contains` since an index won't be found if the row number is not present):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    let cell:EventListCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventListCell

    if let indexData = eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row] {
        if let index = arrSelectedRowsBuy.firstIndex(of: indexData.id) {
            cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "checkbox_inactive")
            arrSelectedRowsBuy.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "blue_tick")
            arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(indexData.id)
        }
    }
}
```

The original code was not keeping the `arrSelectedRowsBuy` in row order. If that's not required then using a `Set` instead of an `Array` makes the code a little cleaner and more efficient:

```
var arrSelectedRowsBuy:Set<Int> = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    let cell:EventListCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventListCell

    if let indexData = eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row] {
        if arrSelectedRowsBuy.remove(indexData.id) != nil {
            cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "checkbox_inactive")
        } else {
            cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "blue_tick")
            arrSelectedRowsBuy.insert(indexData.id)
        }
    }
}
```

If the order is important then an `IndexSet` could be used to store the row indexes (yes, going back to that!) with a computed property to calculate the data model ids from that:

```
var selectedRows = IndexSet()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {

    let cell:EventListCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventListCell

    if selectedRows.remove(indexPath.row) != nil {
        cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "checkbox_inactive")
    } else {
        cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "blue_tick")
        selectedRows.insert(indexPath.row)
    }
}

var arrSelectedRowsBuy: [Int] {
    selectedRows.compactMap { row in
        eventListData?.result?.events?[row].id
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, but it does compile. Of course, this will crash if the data model doesn't actually contain events at `indexPath.row`. It will fail in mysterious ways if there are nils somewhere along the `eventListData?.result?.events?` optional chaining. Quite why the data mode is so full of optionals is a whole separate issue.

Comment: I have no idea about SVG and I am not your personal coding assistant.

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit hard to understand your problem from the given code, but because  you said write an answer, I try to give you some hit by example.

if you define an array and fill it up with you json, now you have an in-order array and indexPath will be equal to your Json, no matter what the ID is. so that "If statement" seems unnecessary and redundant "if arrSelectedRowsBuy.contains(indexPath.row) {
"
because you are sure that you have the current element in your JSON.

```
var JSON = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    JSON.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
```

so you should not search for ID then delete, assume that you don't have ID, you fill your TableView with JSON array, then user select a cell ( for example third one) you delete the third one from your JSON. if you care about the order of ID, you need to sort you JSON before fill up your TableView. I don't know how your JSON structure is, so I just wrote an INT json to demonstrate the code.

Comment: again u removing `indexPath.row` I need selected row `eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` this value will be append/remove from `arrSelectedRowsBuy `

Comment: can you make a small project example upload it and show the problem? OR single file example and put the code here? i need to understand it better. it is a bit obscure now.

Comment: actually its a big project cant upload, i have added code here https://controlc.com/e4a147e6 please once go through here

Comment: and guide me please if i select row then `eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` will be append/remove from `arrSelectedRowsBuy ` not row indexPath

Comment: I didn't mean your real project! I meant simulate your problem in an example project which works so we can run it in see in practice.

Comment: actually i need append/remove selected row `entListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id` in `arrSelectedRowsBuy` can u update answer please